# Is there a better way to write these in python?

Tags: python

Is there a better way to write these lines in python ? for example using a `for`:

```
user.name = form.name.data
user.username = form.username.data
user.password = form.password.data
user.email = form.email.data
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, can you add some context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. Those are doing separate tasks so it makes sense for each to statement to be on its own line. If you find yourself doing this repetitively, you can wrap it in a function if you'd like

```
def setUserData(user, form):
    user.name = form.name.data
    user.username = form.username.data
    user.password = form.password.data
    user.email = form.email.data
```

Then whenever you want to do these operations, you can just say

```
>>> setUserData(user, form)
```

Comment: You could potentially generalize and map over a list of field names? But that sacrifices efficiency for comprehensibility.

Answer (score 4):

```
for el in ('name', 'username', 'password', 'email'):
    setattr(user, el, getattr(form, el).data)
```

anyway as per python zen 'Simple is better than complex', do not see anything wrong with your code